# JDBC ResultSet Data to HashMap

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am not able to set the data from ResultSet to HashMap.

My Query is returning 4 records, but HashMap is holding Last 2 records only. However, in the loop I am able to print 4 records data.
Can any one help?

Here is my code:

```
workOrderMap=new HashMap<String, Integer>();

Statement statement = serviceconnection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT OPERATION,WORKORDERID FROM History WHERE OPERATION='CREATE'OR OPERATION='UPDATE'");
workOrderMap=new HashMap<String, Integer>();

while (rs.next()) {
    workOrderMap.put(rs.getString("OPERATION"), rs.getInt("WORKORDERID"));
    System.out.println(rs.getString("OPERATION")); // loops 4 times
}

System.out.println("List of Workorder id's" + workOrderMap.size()); // prints 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 2 distinct values returned from `rs.getString("OPERATION")`.

This is hardly surprising, considering your `WHERE` clause only allows there to be 2 values:

```
WHERE OPERATION='CREATE' OR OPERATION='UPDATE'
```

In a `Map`, the keys are unique, so calling `put()` with the *same* key value will *overwrite* the value previously there.

---

When converting rowsets to a POJO, I prefer creating a `List<Map<String, Object>>` - each element of the list is a row, each entry in the associated Map are the column names and their values.

---

FYI, your `WHERE` clause can be written more elegantly as:

```
WHERE OPERATION IN ('CREATE', 'UPDATE')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the keys are same, You will see only 2 values in hashmap.

Example

```
Map<String,Integer>  workOrderMap=new HashMap<String, Integer>();

workOrderMap.put("S", 1);
workOrderMap.put("S", 1);
workOrderMap.put("S2", 1);

System.out.println(workOrderMap.size());
```

OUTPUT : 2